# How can I design functionality that allows users to import their own .FBX files into an unreal engine 4 scene on oculus quest 2?

Tags: amazon-s3, unreal-engine4, oculus, fbx

I want to allow users to import a 3d file from a remote AWS s3 bucket. The app will run on the oculus quest 2 platform. Someone will be able to upload a 3d file to the s3 bucket and choose from the files they want to import on the oculus. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

So basically you need to find how to do

1. Loading from AWS bucket
2. Reading mesh data from file (there are many 3d file formats, for ex. fbx, dao, obj)
3. Render mesh in runtime

To generate meshes in runtime you can use Epic's ProceduralMeshComponent or 3rd party project [RuntimeMeshComponent](https://github.com/TriAxis-Games/RuntimeMeshComponent)